# How to disable the dropdown while editing form option?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

```
<FormField
  form={props.form}
  name={'DataLocationId'}
  label={t('projectForm.field.dataCenter.label')}
  fieldType={'select'}
  message={`${t('common.required')}`}
  required
  options={dataLocations}
  isDisabled={true}
  selected={dataLocations.find(d => d.value === initialProperties?.DataLocationId)}
/>
```

```
        case 'select':
            return (
                <Field
                    name={this.props.name}
                    label={this.props.label}
                    conf={this.props}
                    component={SelectField}
                    className="bnt-hc-inputs-input"
                    type="select"
                    options={this.props.options}
                    form={this.props.form}
                    selected={this.props.selected}
                />
            );
```

I want to disable dropdown if the value is already selected in the edit form option. I have added `Isdisabled ={true}` but it's not working.

Comment: where is `FormField` coming from? the prop name is probably `disabled` by the way

Comment: case 'select':
                return (
                    <Field
                        name={this.props.name}
                        label={this.props.label}
                        conf={this.props}
                        component={SelectField}
                        className="bnt-hc-inputs-input"
                        type="select"
                        options={this.props.options}
                        form={this.props.form}
                        selected={this.props.selected}
                    />
                );

Answer (score 0):

passing isDisabled to Field will probably solve your problem;

```
  case 'select':
            return (
                <Field
                    name={this.props.name}
                    label={this.props.label}
                    conf={this.props}
                    component={SelectField}
                    className="bnt-hc-inputs-input"
                    type="select"
                    options={this.props.options}
                    form={this.props.form}
                    selected={this.props.selected}
                    disabled={this.props.isDisabled} // <-- this is the line you need to add
                />
            );
```

Assuming `Field` component has disabled prop